# ARSCNView created by code is slower than storyboard when opening

Tags: ios, objective-c, arkit

I try to use code to create the ARSCNView in the viewDidLoad like below:

```
_sceneView = [[ARSCNView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
_sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_sceneView];
ARWorldTrackingConfiguration *configuration = [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration new];
configuration.worldAlignment = ARWorldAlignmentGravityAndHeading;
configuration.lightEstimationEnabled = YES;
[_sceneView.session runWithConfiguration:configuration];
```

And then I open it by using code:

```
MyARViewController *vc = [[MyARViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I can obviously feel that at the beginning it's stuck a little bit moment and then work as usual while it's smooth to open the view if I use storyboard to create the ARSCNView.

What might be to cause this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the code inside `viewDidLoad` make it stuck?

Comment: If I use storyboard to do this kind of stuff "_sceneView = [[ARSCNView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:_sceneView];" the issue won't be there. I guess something related to the code I created ARSCNView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you added `ARSCNView`.

When you use `StoryBoard` to add `ARSCNView`, the `initWithCoder` method of `ARSCNView` will be called instead of `initWithFrame`. I guess that you did something in `initWithFrame` and you don't do anything inside `initWithCoder`.

That's why you have a difference between adding `ARSCNView` programmatically and adding from `StoryBoard`

**UPDATE**

Another problem is the way you create `MyARViewController` when using `StoryBoard`. `MyARViewController *vc = [[MyARViewController alloc] init];` isn't right way to create `MyARViewController` from StoryBoard. `ARSCNView` can't be added to `MyARViewController`. That's why you don't feed stuck.

Comment: I didn't do anything inside initWithCoder, that's true. But I'm not sure what should I do when I create the ARSCNView in the initWithCoder. Any suggest?

Comment: I think your stuck is because of the code inside `initWithFrame` method of `ARSCNView`. if you create `ARSCNView` from StoryBoard or Xib, you should put the code to `initWithCoder` instead of `initWithFrame`.

Comment: I guess you did something expensive inside `initWithFrame`

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't do anything inside initWithFrame.

Comment: As i said, the difference between adding programmatically and adding from StoryBoard is `initWithCoder` and `initWithFrame`

Comment: @OtakuFitness how did you create `MyARViewController` when you use storyboard?

Comment: drag a view controller into the storyboard, and then drag the ARSCNView into the view controller.